# Primitive properties for a class in init block - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, initialization

I'm defining a Kotlin class with a number of primitive properties:

```
class Contract (contractEntity : ContractEntity) EntityDao<ContractEntity> {
    var id : Long // <- This is a primitive datatype, needs to be initialized
    var concept : String //<- This also needs to be initialized or declared abstract

    init{
        mapFromEntity(contractEntity)
    }

    override fun mapFromEntity(entity : ContractEntity){
        id = entity.id
        concept = entity.concept
    }
}
```

Now, I want those properties to be initialized with the function `mapFromEntity()` but I'm stuck with the init block because those are not initialized. What could be a good way to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: You can initialize them with default values (0 and "" for example). `concept` can be declared as a lateinit var, too.

Comment: I don't want to use default values. This class must get the values from the Entity class

Comment: And it will get them as soon as the init block is executed. So no one will ever see the default values. If you really don't want default values, then use `var id = contractEntity.id`

Comment: I don't think you have choices apart from what @JBNizet suggested if you want to keep the current setup intact. The option I would go for is to move this "mapping" to a factory method that takes in a `ContractEntity` and returns a `Contract`. But maybe it's not possible because of the framework you're using.

Comment: You're right. I think I'm still too Java-shaped. Moving to Kotlin seems great but I still struggle with this things.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best solution suggest to remove the function that maps the class and use the constructor parameter.

```
class Contract (contractEntity : ContractEntity) EntityDao<ContractEntity> {
    var id = contractEntity.id
    var concept = contractEntity.concept
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

Placeholder code so that this will compile:

```kotlin
sealed interface Entity
data class ContractEntity(val id: Long, val concept: String) : Entity

interface EntityDao<T : Entity, R> {
    fun mapFromEntity(entity: T): R
}
```

Convert this to a data class, where `id` and `concept` are immutable properties in the primary constructor. Then, add a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) that implements `EntityDao`.

```kotlin
data class Contract(val id: Long, val concept: String) {

    companion object : EntityDao<ContractEntity, Contract> {
        override fun mapFromEntity(entity: ContractEntity): Contract {
            return Contract(
                id = entity.id,
                concept = entity.concept
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val contractEntity = ContractEntity(id = 0, concept = "")
    val contract = Contract.mapFromEntity(contractEntity)
}
```